# Slurm on AWS returns slurmstepd: error: execve(): : No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, slurm

I have installed a Burstable and Event-driven HPC Cluster on AWS Using [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com) according to [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deploying-a-burstable-and-event-driven-hpc-cluster-on-aws-using-slurm-part-1/).

With this installation I can burst instances and run jobs in the Slurm environment on EC2. After running:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --constraint=[us-east-1a]
```

`$sinfo` returns:

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
all*         up   infinite      2   idle ip-10-0-1-[6-7]
gpu          up   infinite      2   idle ip-10-0-1-[6-7]
```

When I try to run system commands like `hostname` I get responses from the nodes however when I try to execute a custom executable as simple as `helloworld` in `C` with this:

```
$srun --export=ALL -N 2 -n 2 ./helloworld
```

It returns:

```
Exited with exit code 2
slurmstepd: error: execve(): /home/centos/./helloworld: No such file or directory.
```

What do I need to set to proper submit my custom jobs?

Comment: Did you try `$srun --export=ALL -N 2 -n 2 helloworld` ?

Comment: yes, it returns: `slurmstepd: error: execve(): helloworld: No such file or directory`

Comment: I know this is self-answered, but another tip is to run your Bash script with the `-l` flag to pass on environment variables of the user running the script. So this, `#!/bin/bash` becomes this `#!/bin/bash -l`,

Answer (score 2):

The executable was not automatically copied to all the nodes, like it does on the clusters I had worked on before. I had to explicitly tell `srun` to do that.

```
srun --export=ALL --bcast=/home/centos/helloworld -N 2 -n 2 helloworld
```

Copies the executable and executes it on the nodes. Or you could use `sbcast` in Bash.